# Elixir/Phoenix file upload folder with relative path

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I referenced under URL tips.

[Elixir/Phoenix file upload folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501912/elixir-phoenix-file-upload-folder)

I have same question. I wonder why I can't move uploaded file to dest folder.
In case of absolute path, it works. 
How can I set the relative path settings?

upload_controller.ex

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.UploadController do
  use MyAppWeb, :controller

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    IO.inspect user_params
    if upload = user_params["photo"] do
      extension = Path.extname(upload.filename)

      # It worked.
      # File.cp(upload.path, "/Users/myaccount/MyApp/priv/static/media/profile#{extension}") 

      # It didn't work.
      case File.cp(upload.path, "media/profile#{extension}") do
        {:ok, _result} ->
          conn
          |> put_flash(:info, "File Uploaded successfully.")
          |> redirect(to: upload_path(conn, :index))
        {:error, _result} ->
          IO.inspect(_result)
          conn
          |> put_flash(:info, "File Uploaded failed!!.")
          |> redirect(to: upload_path(conn, :index))
      end
    end
  end
```

endpoint.ex

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/", from: :fish_pot, gzip: false,
  only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)

#Added
plug Plug.Static, at: "/uploads", from: "media/"
```

I would like to upload files in `priv/static/media`. IO.inspect returns `:enoent`.

Comment: How exactly it fails? What did you try?

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply.

Comment: Please check the pwd.

Comment: pwd shows Project root path. `File.cp(upload.path, "priv/static/media/profile#{extension}")` worked. But it normal way?